# Creating a tree of required items

Tags: c#

As I am developing my small game, I have made a lot of progress yet frustrated about a lot of things. The latest thing was `creating a list of required items` and for you to understand that I will provide you with both `Explanation` as well as `Code` which I created but obviously doesn't work...

I - Explanation

In order for the player to build a building he must have done some required researches with each research requires more researches for it to be researched... It is like a tree of researches that the player will go through them by exploring the game and doing some tasks...

So to imagine it more accurately you can look at my small *code* here

II - Code

```
    //Available Main Elements
    var carbon = new Element {Name = "Carbon"};
    var hydrogen = new Element {Name = "Hydrogen"};
    var oxygen = new Element {Name = "Oxygen"};
    var nitrogen = new Element {Name = "Nitrogen"};

        //Example Research
var steam = new Research(name : "Steam", requiredElements: null, requiredResearches: /*Fire*/ & /*Water*/ & /*Iron*/);
```

So from the last snippet of code [which is just to explain] the player want to research the `Steam` that for instance needs 3 more researches in order to be researched... one of which `the Iron` also needs 1 more research to be researched and so on [maybe less maybe more or maybe no requirements at all]...

Concluding that the Question is : *How could I create such nesting so that when a player tries to do a research the system quickly looks at the researches he have done and the research he wants to do [including it's nested ones] and If the player did not meet the requirements it just returns a tree with what things he want's to achieve* ?

After all, I just want to thank you in advance and I am waiting for your very valuable support...

Comment: Would it be ok to assume that if the player has a required research 'A' then he also has all researches that 'A' depends on, or do you want to ensure all 'sub-researches' have also been done every time?

Comment: Do you have a list of researches completed?

Comment: In order to complete research 'A', wouldn't he have to have all of its sub-researches anyway?

Comment: @Cemafor : yea I a must make sure that all the sub researches of each research [ also each research's sub researches ] :D are done.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen as I told on the last comment.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen: I would assume so, but I wanted to check if he was ok making that assumption. I guess there could be a way for a player to be granted a research somehow without all of the sub-researches (some sort of special event or whatever), but that should not allow them to reasearch further up the tree.

Comment: One suggestion I'll make that's unrelated to your actual question: Increase the size of your vocabulary a bit, and I don't mean that in a negative way. E.g. you say "must have done some required researches with each research requires more researches for it to be researched". When naming your properties and relationships in code, things like `Prerequisites` to indicate a collection of Research items required for the current Research item, and `LeadsTo` for a collection of "unlocked" Research items. This will make your code more readable and maintainable.

Comment: @Steve: thank you for your point of view, I will take into account for sure... but the reason I missed that out was that I was a bit in hurry... and I am sorry for any inconvenience

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would remove the requirement logic out of the Research objects themselves. For simplicity say it was this:

```
public class Research
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then, I would keep a list of the requirements in a `Dictonary` where each `Research` contains a bucket of other `Researches`:

```
Dictionary<Research, List<Research>> requiredResearches = 
    new Dictionary<Research, List<Research>>();

// the list of Researches the player has completed
List<Research> playersResearched = new List<Research>;
```

For example, "Steam" would contain "Fire", "Water" and "Iron". And maybe "Iron" contains "Tin".

Next, given a Research, we could look at all of it's requierements including requirements of requirements:

```
// e.g. research is "Steam" and returns "Fire", "Water", "Iron", "Tin"
var chainOfRequirements = GetReq(requiredResearches, research);
```

That calls a recursive function like this:

```
public IList<Research> GetReq(Dictionary<Research, List<Research>> reqs, 
                              Research target)
{
    var chain = new List<Research>();
    if(reqs.ContainsKey(target))
    {
        foreach(var item in reqs[target])
        {
            chain.Add(item);
            chain.AddRange(GetReq(reqs, item));
        }
    }
    return chain;
}
```

What you are returned is a flat list of requirements (including requirements of requirements). At that point, a little query against the players list of `Researches` can return to you which ones that are missing:

```
var missing = chainOfRequirements.Where (c => 
                  playerResearches.Where (r => r == c).Any () == false).Distinct();
```

## TO ENABLE COMPARING DICTIONARY USING "NAME"

```
public sealed class NameEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Research>
{
    public bool Equals(Research x, Research y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(y, null)) return false;
        if (x.GetType() != y.GetType()) return false;
        return string.Equals(x.Name, y.Name);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Research obj)
    {
        return (obj.Name != null ? obj.Name.GetHashCode() : 0);
    }
}
```

[Here is proof of concept.](http://ideone.com/EbMlup)

Comment: Sorry but what If I wanted to add a prerequisite of a prerequisite I mean what if "Tin" also needed something else. Cause as I stated it `A research might have 1 prerequisite, none, or even up to 10 prerequisites with each of them needing the same thing...

Comment: @Eric, yep, that would completely work. Although, you'd probably want to tweak the `GetReq` method so that it wasn't adding any duplicates (or remove them before your last test). I've included a link to some code. Check that out and play with it.

Comment: so far your answer is the most clear yet you just made me wonder what if there are duplicates and I wanna distinguish them :D. Excuse me for that bit of stupidity I have in that topic but I hope you have some patience for me :D

Comment: @Eric, `Distinct()`. Simply add `Distinct()` to the end of your query like my above edit.

Comment: Ok we are almost there :D. but testing your code, I get no thing our of the missing variable although I am sat it up as the player have not completed any research. When I debugged it. it seems that when I create a new variable to indicated the research to search for by the recrusive function it did not get past the `if (reqs.ContainsKey(target))`... although I already added a research with that name at the dictionary. Also it does not get all the requirements of requirements

Comment: It seems that somehow the recrusive function does not recognize the Research by it's Name

Comment: ? it seems that you got bored from me :D

Comment: @Eric, I think I know: try changing all the Research type in the dictionary and list to type string and just pass the name of the Research items.

Comment: mmm I think I know the reason is that the Research objects already added the dictionary have different Hash Code than that of the new item I created to search with... I think I must override the Equal function of the Research Class

Comment: I got bas that with a small class. I have edited your answer to include that. Also I want to state that there is something wrong about the part that returns missing Researches because it returns all the researches including the ones that the player already have...

Comment: @Eric, yes, the problem is it is comparing the instances and not the Names. I think it would be more efficient just to change the Dictionary and List types from `Record` to `string` and just store the names of the Researches.  You could always use the name to hit your collection of Researches to pull out the actual Research object.  Oh, and for missing, a quick fix is `r.Name == c.Name`.

Comment: I was just coming to say what you have said after I gave it a test :D... also take a look at the edit I made to your answer

Comment: it is kinda working very nice right now, accept my apologizes for my bunch of questions :D and I really thank you for you very nice help. Also accept me to send you a pm if I needed something in the future regarding this topic (if face some probs).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know `C#` well enough to provide code, but you could make each `Research` have an `Array` of type `Research`, that would hold the `Research` that must be done to be able to make the actual `Research`, then you only need to iterate the `Array` checking if all of them are completed.

You don't even need to check the requirements of the requirements, as if they are completed, they already have all requirements completed.

If the `Research` don't have any requirements you just let the `Array` empty.

Comment: In my case I must check for the requirements of the requirements as the player may encounter a research that is too high for his level or something so I must give him a detailed information of what he should do in order to be able to complete that research...

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to add `bool completed` to the `Element` and `Research` classes. You could then have a function that checks for `completed == false` for any of its sub-researches.

```
bool CanCompleteResearch(Research r)
{
    for (Research sub in r.requiredResearches)
    {
        // No need to recursively check 'sub'; in order for 'sub' to be marked as
        // completed, its sub-researches must've been already completed.            
        if (!sub.completed)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I'm sure there's some one-liner trick you can do with LINQ.

**EDIT:** this only works if a research tree is not being used in more than one place at once (i.e. if you had the research objects shared across multiple player instances).

**EDIT 2:** In order to figure out all the missing research, you can use a simple recursive function:

```
void ListMissingResearch(Research r)
{
    for (Research sub in r.requiredResearches)
    {
        if (!sub.completed)
        {
            // print message saying "Research <r> requires research <sub>"
            ListMissingResearch(sub); // list any missing sub-sub-research
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case I must check for the requirements of the requirements as the player may encounter a research that is too high for his level or something so I must give him a detailed information of what he should do in order to be able to complete that research... So I have to check for the sub researches of each research recursively

Comment: Yea, you could (again, using LINQ) grab a list of all the uncompleted required researches, and do whatever recursively with those research trees.

Comment: Can you explain this with codes. Also I will repeat what I want in order to make it clear... every research has prerequisites and every prerequisite has sub prerequisites and so on it might change depending on the situation... So for example you might have a research with no prerequisites at all on the other hand you may have a research with 10 prerequisites... So what made me want to also get the list of all that sub prerequisites is that I want the user to know what he is missing on order to finish his mission also I want to user them in another methods...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you make your own `requirementsTree` class, which would need to be a linked list with at least the following members:

- a `requirementsTree[] prerequisiteResearch` property, containing all of the research required for that particular item.
- a `bool isResearched` property, indicating if the player has in fact researched the item.
- a method, say, `bool isEligibleToResearch()`, which loops through all of the items in `prerequisiteResearch` to check if the player has already researched them.

With this I think you'd have a well-structured and extensible requirements class.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any specific things that would prevent this from happening, but I can see why you'd be hesitant to just jump into coding it without having thought through the cases. To try to give some pointers, here are some functions I would imagine you having by the end:

```
// Having a function to retrieve a unique variable by its name (backed by a Dictionary<string, Research>)
// is often handy for me, especially if you decide to script the requirements tree in a text file.
// If you have enough references passed around that you can do this without a static method, all
// the better.
Research.getResearchByName(string name)

// A recursive function. If this research has not been completed, it adds itself to the set, as well
// as any prerequisites (by calling this function on its prerequisites). The top-level, public
// version of this function would create the set, and then return it after performing this check. If
// the Set is empty, then the player can start the research.
Research.addUnresearched_Internal(Set<Research> unresearched)
```

I think the main issue with my approach here is that I only thought to use a Set, rather than a Tree;
but with some bit of variation, you might be able to do better than me.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to do something like this:

```
public class Research
{
    private Collection<Research> prerequisites 
    public Collection<Research> Prerequisites 
    {
        get { return this.prerequisistes; }
    }

    public bool IsComplete { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Research> RequiredResearch()
    {
        if (this.IsComplete)
        {
            return new Research[0];
        } 
        else 
        {
            return new[] { this }.Concat(
                this.Prerequisites.SelectMany(r => r.RequiredResearch()));
        }
    }
}
```

If you're making a multi-player, it might have to be something like this:

```
public class Player
{
    private Collection<Research> completedResearch
    public Collection<Research> CompletedResearch
    {
        get { return this.completedResearch; }
    }
}

public class Research
{
    private Collection<Research> prerequisites 
    public Collection<Research> Prerequisites 
    {
        get { return this.prerequisistes; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Research> RequiredResearch(Player player)
    {
        if (player.CompletedResearch.Contains(this))
        {
            return new Research[0];
        } 
        else 
        {
            return new[] { this }.Concat(
                this.Prerequisites.SelectMany(r => r.RequiredResearch(player)));
        }
    }
}
```

Both these methods will return the current research if it has not been completed (instead of just it's prerequisites). You could simply do a `.Skip(1)` on the result to ignore the current one, though.

Comment: What I want to do then is recursively check the sub Prerequisites if the function returned false so that I can return the player a list of researches he miss in order to complete the task...

Comment: in order to make it a bit clear I will explain it again... Every research has prerequisites and every prerequisite has sub prerequisites and so on. It might vary depending on the situation... So for example, you might have a research with no prerequisites at all , while ,on the other hand, you may have a research with up to 10 prerequisites [each with it's own prerequisite(s)]... So what made me want to also get the list of all that sub prerequisites is that I want the user to know what he is missing on order to finish his mission also I want to user them in another methods...

Comment: @ErricJManderin See my updated answer. The method will now return all the `Research` which are needed to complete the goal.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a function like this in your research class that just takes in an enumerable list of `Research`s you use to check that the player has the prerequisits.  This assumes there is a local list or some other enumerable of `Research`es called `Prereqs` in the `Research` class.

```
public bool CanHas(IEnumerable<Research> researches)
{
   return Prereqs.All((pr) => researches.Contains(pr) && pr.CanHas(researches));
}
```

The function just recursivly checks each Prereq to see if it is in the list passed in, and then checks that prereqs prereqs. `All` is a linq extention method that just returns true if all of the elements in the enumerable meet the criteria.  If there are no elements, it returns true (all zero of the elements meet the criteria) so this will terminate when you get down to a `Research` with no Prereqs.

Note: This does a depth first search and is not smart about the same research being a sub-research of more then one prerequisite.

Comment: Feel free to change the name of the function ;)